# Linking boost (c++) using cython

Tags: python, c++, boost, include, cython

I am getting this error when i try to run a test after implementing a functionality in my c++ code.

```
tests/pipeline/feature_extraction/test_rolling_windows.py:5: in <module>
    from pipeline.feature_extraction.rolling_window.windows import (
E   ImportError: /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/data-science/pipeline/feature_extraction/rolling_window/windows.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN5boost7archive6detail14basic_oarchiveE
```

I have this setup.py where i'm linking boost.

```
setup(
    version="1.0.0",
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        Extension(
            "windows",
            sources=["rolling_window.pyx"],
            include_dirs=[np.get_include(), "/usr/local/include", "/usr/local/include/boost", "/usr/local/lib"],
            language="c++",
            extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11", "-lboost_serialization", "-lboost_filesystem", "-lboost_archive",'-lboost_system ','-Wno-unused-local-typedef'],
            extra_link_args=["-std=c++11"],
            library_dirs = ["/usr/local/lib", "/usr/local/include", "/usr/local/include/boost"]
        ),
        compiler_directives={"language_level": "3"},
    )
)
```

I have these *#includes* in my .h file

```
#ifndef LRUCACHE_H
#define LRUCACHE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
    Value loadFromDisk(const Key& key) {
        
        std::string filename = filename_ + "_" + std::to_string(key) + ".txt";
        std::ifstream inFile(filename);
        if (boost::filesystem::exists(filename)) {
            boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(inFile);
            Value readBuffer;
            ia >> readBuffer;
            inFile.close();
            return readBuffer;
        }
        throw std::runtime_error("Entity not found in disk");
    }
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Link boost statically with your C++ code. What version of C++ are you on? C++17 has filesystem build in (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem). If boost is not strictly required then just leave it out. Maybe a std::file (instead of a boost iarchive will work too).

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion.
Using -static doesn't seem to work.
I'm using C++11 unfortunately, can't upgrade it to 17 because of my gcc version

Comment: I never really experienced big problems with upgrading from C++11 to C++17. But that is also the result of having a lot of unit tests. Still it might be worth to setup a test build with a newer version of gcc enable C++17 (or even C++20) and see how much problems there are.